# How to assign individual attributes to Any Logic Agents

Tags: attributes, agent, anylogic

I would like to solve the following issue:

- agent based model with a population of 500 agents
- each agent gets assigned with an ID number using a variable called v_agentID using the order v_agentID++; after being created
- The agent should then be further processed based on a condition monitoring the individual waiting time

How can I assign individual attributes like waiting times (as a result of the calculation waitingTime=waitingTimeEnd-waitingTimeStart)to each individual agent?

Thanks a lot for your help.

Bastian

Answer (score 0):

Many ways:

1) create a cyclical event on the individual agent that calculates waitingTime with the formula you provided
2) create a dynamic variable for each agent and make it equal to waitingTimeEnd-waitingTimeStart
3) create the variable whenever you want and change it in all the agents:

```
for(Agent a : agents){
    a.waitingTime=a.waitingTimeEnd-a.waitingTimeStart;
}
```

4) Find the agent with the id you want and assign the variable to it

```
Agent theAgent=findFirst(agents,a->a.id=theIdYouWant);
theAgent.waitingTime=theAgent.waitingTimeEnd-theAgent-waitingTimeStart;
```

5) If you know the index of the agent just do

```
agents.get(index).waitingTime=agents.get(index).waitingTimeEnd-agents.get(index).waitingTimeStart
```

Comment: Hi felipe, I tried the suggested approach but it seems I still do not really understand the concept.

Comment: Hi felipe, I tried the suggested approach but it seems I still do not really understand the concept. As I am quite a beginner in AnyLogic I am using the graphical support of the statecharts. Maybe I would need to do this even simpler, can you maybe explain me what the "for" loop you wrote under point 3 is doing and what of the used words are variables I would need to define and what is code recognized by Any Logic. --> sorry for asking again but again, I am unfortunatly quite a beginner